# React-Test-Render call component method

Tags: reactjs, react-test-renderer

I have the following component:

```
export const FormikInput: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
   const handleChange = (value: string) => {
       // do something
       props.setFieldValue(props.key, value);


    return (
           <TextField
            label={props.label}
            onChangeText={handleChange}
            value={props.values[props.key]}
        />
);
```

};

And I want to call the `handleChange` method user react-test-renderer
Is that possible?

Comment: listen react-test-render is for snapshot testing. Are you doing component behavioral testing then you should do shallow rendering and mock the handle change function.

Comment: yes i want to test the behaviour of my handlechange function. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score -1):

Give a `classname` to `TextField` and mock your `handleChange` like this:

```
describe('handleChange event success', () => {
it('handleChange invokes without throwing an error', () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent
      handleChange ={handleChange}
       />);
    wrapper.find('.myTextField').simulate('change');
    expect(handleChange ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

There might be some tweaks needed for your TS, I have written this for JS

Comment: this is `enzyme`, the question is about `react-test-denderer`